# SQL divide by zero with a sum function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having problems with dividing by zero.  If the denominator is zero I would like the value to be zero.  When I try using `nullif`, I end up with a zero or one for the calculated value.

Here is the SQL:

```
Select 
    StateCode, Month1Date,(Sum(Order)/Sum(Value)) as myValue    
from tblOrders    
     inner join tblStates on OrderStateCode = StateCode    
group by StateCode, Month1Date
```

Comment: Man, i always have the problem! Dividing by zero, who told me you can't do that.....I think it was my first grade teacher! :D   You should use a case statement to check is sum(value) = 0 and if it it, don't divide!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select
  StateCode,
  Month1Date,
  ISNULL(Sum(Order) / NULLIF(Sum(Value), 0), 0) AS myValue
from
  tblOrders
inner join
  tblStates
    on OrderStateCode = StateCode
group by
  StateCode,
  Month1Date
```

A `0` denominator is changed to `NULL`, which will cause the `result` to be `NULL`.  The whole result then has `ISNULL()` to turn any NULLs to 0's.

Personally I would *not* include the `ISNULL()` and leave the result as `NULL`.  But it depends on use-case really.

**EDIT:** Deleted the CASE WHEN version as another answer had it just before mine.

Answer (score 5):

You need a case statement:

```
Select StateCode, Month1Date,
        (case when sum(value) = 0 then 0 else Sum(Order)/Sum(Value)
         end) as myValue
from tblOrders inner join
     tblStates
     on OrderStateCode = StateCode
group by StateCode, Month1Date
```

Comment: Related reading: [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case)

Comment: That is a good reading.  It seems to apply specifically to the aggregations, not to combinations of them.  It would be sad if the above syntax failed, since that would leave few other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT StateCode, Month1Date,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Value) <> 0 THEN(SUM(Order)/SUM(Value))
        ELSE 0 END as myValue
    FROM tblOrders 
    INNER JOIN tblStates ON OrderStateCode = StateCode 
    GROUP BY StateCode, Month1Date
```